# Is it possible to change verbiage of listAuditEvents?

Tags: docusignapi

The current [Envelopes: listAuditEvents] creates the following verbiage for correction:

     `"eventFields": [
                {
                    "name": "logTime",
                    "value": "2018-09-18T19:09:01.3603686Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Source",
                    "value": "api"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserName",
                    "value": "Staging"
                },
                {
                    "name": "UserId",
                    "value": "8c57af14-e46a-4965-ae8b-42bb0c29b706"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Action",
                    "value": "Correction Initiated"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Message",
                    "value": "Staging initiated correction"
                },
                {
                    "name": "EnvelopeStatus",
                    "value": "correct"
                },`

I would like to modify the Message values.  I have gone through Docusigns API but I have not found any indication that this is possible.

Has anyone had the same need?  and if so were you able to add custom message verbiage for certain events/actions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible for you to configure the contents of the API response for the **listAuditEvents** operation. However, you could (in your code) include logic to parse the API response and based on certain values in the response, substitute values (for purposes in your app) with the verbiage you prefer.

For example, let's say that you have a page in your app that displays the various events that have occurred for an Envelope, but you don't want to display the verbiage "[UserName] initiated correction" as the text in your UI when a user initiates an envelope correction -- instead you want to display the text "[UserName] changed envelope settings." The logic in your code could do something like this psuedo code shows (where `auditEvent` represents an object within the API response body for the **listAuditEvents** operation):

```
if (auditEvent.ActionInitiated == "Correction Initiated") {
   displayMessageInUI(auditEvent.UserName + " changed envelope settings.");
}
```

Comment: This is true... was hoping not to have to add code... but I agree with your assessment.